# Changing stacked chart to staggered in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm struggling to change a stacked chart into a staggered one in ggplot2. So far this is what I've created [Attempt 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ZzyK.png). I'm trying to show how much of three different types of medicines are necessary to kill 16 different types of bacteria. I feel like the graph would be a lot clearer if I could put these bars right next to each other for each bacteria type instead of stacked.
This is the code that I've used so far. I've tried using position dodge but I get no results.

```
p2b <- ggplot() + 
         geom_bar(data=p2, aes(x=p2$bacteria, y=p2$penicillin, fill='transparent'), 
                  position="dodge", colour = "blue", fill="transparent", stat = "identity") + 
         geom_bar(data=p2, aes(x=p2$bacteria, y=p2$streptomycin, position="dodge"), 
                  colour = "red", fill = "transparent", stat = "identity") + 
         geom_bar(data=p2, aes(x=p2$bacteria, y=p2$neomycin, position="dodge"), 
                  colour = "green", fill = "transparent", stat = "identity")  + 
         scale_y_log10() + 
         theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```

Comment: Can you provide a data sample that we can run your code on? For example, to provide the first ten rows of your data, post the output of `dput(p2[1:10,])`, but you should provide a minimal set of rows from your data frame that illustrate the issue you're trying to resolve.

Comment: For starters, within `aes` you should reference only columns names, not data frames (e.g., `x=bacteria` rather than `x=p2$bacteria`). The `data=p2` argument takes care of passing the data frame to `geom_bar`.

Comment: Second, you should put your data into "long" format so that you need only one call to `geom_bar`, rather than three. It will be easier to illustrate if you post a data sample.

Comment: eipi10, thank you so much for your helpful reply. I have created exactly what I wanted by taking your advice :) I specifically changed my data to the long format and then referenced only column names (I'm new to R so tips to clean up my code are super helpful!)